# How are the various Docker container build tools related to one another?

Tags: docker

The Docker technology stack has evolved multiple different tools for building container images, like `docker build` and `docker-compose build` and `docker buildx build` and `docker buildx bake` and `buildctl`.

How do these relate to each other? And what is recommended for a new Docker-based project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my incomplete understanding.

At first Docker Engine provided an API endpoint for requesting a build of a container image from a Dockerfile. The Docker CLI build command, `docker build`, invoked this API according to its command line options.

Then `docker-compose` (Docker Compose V1) came around and provided a way to describe the build options for a container image in YAML, invoking the same Docker Engine API.

In 2017, Docker [started](https://www.docker.com/blog/introducing-the-moby-project/) the [Moby Project](https://blog.mobyproject.org) with the intention of creating open source backend components for working with containers.

One these components is [BuildKit](https://blog.mobyproject.org/introducing-buildkit-17e056cc5317), which is like a compiler for container images. It builds images from a low-level build definition format called LLB. Frontend tools can translate inputs including, but not limited to, Dockerfiles into LLB. (`buildctl` is just a tool for interacting with BuildKit from the command line.)

An important thing to note is that BuildKit is independent from the Docker Engine. As BuildKit matured, existing tools aimed to switch from using the Docker Engine API to using BuildKit.

The Docker CLI `buildx` plugin provides one command line interface for invoking BuildKit. `docker buildx build` builds a single container image from command line options, and `docker buildx bake` can read those options from a `docker-compose.yml` file.

Eventually, the normal `docker build` command learned to be able to use BuildKit. This mode has to be enabled by setting the `DOCKER_BUILDKIT` environment variable, or a `daemon.json` configuration option. This is the default on Docker Desktop.

Until now, `docker-compose` used the Docker Engine API directly. A new `COMPOSE_DOCKER_CLI_BUILD` environment variable was added to instead invoke `docker build`. Most recently, the tool was rewritten from scratch, and [Docker Compose V2](https://www.docker.com/blog/announcing-compose-v2-general-availability/) (now `docker compose`) can invoke BuildKit itself. The `COMPOSE_DOCKER_CLI_BUILD` option is not supported anymore.